# Unable to run simple HelloWorld JavaFx Application on a Raspberry Pi Model 3 and Java 11

Tags: java, raspberry-pi3, gluon, openjfx

I'm unable to run the [Gluon JavaFx](http://docs.gluonhq.com/embedded/#_run_the_application_on_the_device) sample. I did all the step described with the exception of taking the newer [Liberica JDK 11.0.2](http://docs.gluonhq.com/embedded/#_run_the_application_on_the_device) instead of the preview and pointed the `JAVA_HOME` variable to the respective directory.

Executing the demo application using:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java \
 --module-path=/opt/armv6hf-sdk/lib \
 --add-modules=javafx.controls \
 -cp target/classes/ \
 -Dprism.verbose=true \
 -Dembedded=monocle \
 -Dglass.platform=Monocle sample.Main
```

Gives me the following output and error:

```
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw 
Using Double Precision Marlin Rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Using system sized mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2_monocle
    succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.MonocleGLFactory
Dispman: Cannot open display
* failed to add service - already in use?
```

Any ideas, what there could be the problem? I found various tips on stackoverflow like additionally installing the following packages:

```
sudo apt install raspberrypi-ui-mods xorg libgtk2.0-0
```

or doing a firmware update using:

```
sudo rpi-update 192
```

even modifing the `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules` and adding:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input*", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c '\
 chown -R root:input /sys/class/input/*/ && chmod -R 770 /sys/class/input/*/;\
'"
```

did cause any change.

Has anyone a idea what I'm missing or can do to get that running?

Comment: Do you have a monitor plugged? Are you running from SSH or directly from the Raspberry Pi? Do you use X11 or command line?

Comment: Tried it with ssh and directly on the console...

Comment: The Liberica JDK already contains JavaFX, so you can simply try: `sudo $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp target/classes sample.Main`. Can you check if that works?

Comment: Unfortunately I still got the same result:

`pi@raspberrypi:~/MaryHadALittleLambda $ sudo /opt/jdk-11.0.2/bin/java  -cp target/classes sample.Main`
`Dispman: Cannot open display`
`* failed to add service - already in use?`

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /opt/jdk-11.0.2/bin/java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2-BellSoft" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2-BellSoft+7)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 11.0.2-BellSoft+7, mixed mode)

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.14.79-v7+ #1159 SMP Sun Nov 4 17:50:20 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: Liberica also runs from X11. Try to run `startx`, and then open a terminal to run `sudo $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Djavafx.platform=gtk -cp target/classes sample.Main`

Comment: This worked fine. For my use case I search for a possibility to somehow start a Fx Application remote using SSH and a Monitor is attached to the HDMI port. Would this be possible?

Comment: Yes, of course. I typically use it always via SSH, but with a display connected, either via HDMI or the DSI connector.

Comment: What is the correct way to start an application using SSH then? Did I something wrong with my Approach using a minimal installation? Is there a way to get more info when trying to run it remotely?

Comment: I don't know what went wrong in your case. Maybe you could try a regular Raspbian distribution, like [Raspbian Stretch with desktop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/)?

Comment: Using the plain `2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch` and with the current `bellsoft-jdk11.0.2-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz` booting to promt only works perfectly..

Comment: Good to know. That's the distribution I use too. Lite should have worked too, probably some driver was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Use latest [raspbian-stretch](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) image and install the actual [Liberica JDK](https://bell-sw.com/java.html) in the `/opt`folder.

To start a JavaFx application within the X11 environment use the following flags:

`$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Djavafx.platform=gtk -cp <actual-classpath> <main-class-name>`

To start a JavaFx application via SSH or from command line use:

`$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp <actual-classpath> <main-class-name>`

Optionally you can add those flags to get more verbose infos:

`-Dprism.verbose=true -Djavafx.verbose=true`